# Using DELETE with OUTPUT INTO clause not behaving atomic with SqlTransaction

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, sqltransaction

As far as I read, this statement is atomic. Either both will fail or both will succeed:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1
OUTPUT DELETED.* 
INTO TABLE2
WHERE <condition>
```

I have these statements executed through a stored procedure. When I execute said stored procedure, or these statements directly in SSMS, it works perfectly.

But when I call the stored procedure through ADO.NET `SqlCommand` which is part of a transaction, then only the `delete` happens - the `Insert` is not performed.

When I call the stored procedure through ADO.NET `SqlCommand` **without** a transaction, then both `delete` and `insert` happen.

Any clue for this behavior?